# showing this error for pil moule of python

Tags: python

kunal@Kunal ~ $ pip install PIL
Collecting PIL
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PIL

Answer (score 0):

There is no package on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) with the name `PIL`, so `pip` can't find and install it.

There is however a package called [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) which is a fork of PIL.